# Python .lower does not seem to properly lowercase all unicode characters (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm trying to normalize latin unicode characters to their lower case forms.  I thought I could use the .lower function on a unicode object, but it seems that some parts of unicode are not covered - in particular [this block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA720.pdf) has some characters that do not lowercase: 0xa7a0, 0xa7a2, 0xa7b6, 0xa79e, 0xa79a, 0xa790 all return the same character when .lower is called.  I don't anticipate seeing a lot of these characters, so it would be a waste of time to go through all the relevant blocks to fix the ones that don't convert correctly.  Is there a more complete function to lowercase unicode, or is this a locale issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of Python 2 (2.7.11) uses version 5.2.0 of the [Unicode Character Database](http://unicode.org/ucd/), whereas the latest Python 3 (3.5.1) uses version 8.0.0. Earlier versions of Python 3 all use UCD version 6.x.x.

A diff of the tables between [5.2.0](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/5.2.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) and [8.0.0](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt), shows the following list of missing characters in the range (A720-A7FF) you are interested in:

```
-A78D;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED H;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;0265;
-A78E;LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH RETROFLEX HOOK AND BELT;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
-A78F;LATIN LETTER SINOLOGICAL DOT;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
-A790;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH DESCENDER;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A791;
-A791;LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH DESCENDER;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A790;;A790
-A792;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH BAR;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A793;
-A793;LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH BAR;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A792;;A792
-A794;LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH PALATAL HOOK;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
-A795;LATIN SMALL LETTER H WITH PALATAL HOOK;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
-A796;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B WITH FLOURISH;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A797;
-A797;LATIN SMALL LETTER B WITH FLOURISH;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A796;;A796
-A798;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F WITH STROKE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A799;
-A799;LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH STROKE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A798;;A798
-A79A;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER VOLAPUK AE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A79B;
-A79B;LATIN SMALL LETTER VOLAPUK AE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A79A;;A79A
-A79C;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER VOLAPUK OE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A79D;
-A79D;LATIN SMALL LETTER VOLAPUK OE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A79C;;A79C
-A79E;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER VOLAPUK UE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A79F;
-A79F;LATIN SMALL LETTER VOLAPUK UE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A79E;;A79E
-A7A0;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A7A1;
-A7A1;LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A7A0;;A7A0
-A7A2;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A7A3;
-A7A3;LATIN SMALL LETTER K WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A7A2;;A7A2
-A7A4;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A7A5;
-A7A5;LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A7A4;;A7A4
-A7A6;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A7A7;
-A7A7;LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A7A6;;A7A6
-A7A8;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A7A9;
-A7A9;LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH OBLIQUE STROKE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A7A8;;A7A8
-A7AA;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H WITH HOOK;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;0266;
-A7AB;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER REVERSED OPEN E;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;025C;
-A7AC;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SCRIPT G;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;0261;
-A7AD;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH BELT;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;026C;
-A7B0;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED K;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;029E;
-A7B1;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED T;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;0287;
-A7B2;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J WITH CROSSED-TAIL;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;029D;
-A7B3;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER CHI;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;AB53;
-A7B4;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER BETA;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A7B5;
-A7B5;LATIN SMALL LETTER BETA;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A7B4;;A7B4
-A7B6;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;A7B7;
-A7B7;LATIN SMALL LETTER OMEGA;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;A7B6;;A7B6
-A7F7;LATIN EPIGRAPHIC LETTER SIDEWAYS I;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
-A7F8;MODIFIER LETTER CAPITAL H WITH STROKE;Lm;0;L;<super> 0126;;;;N;;;;;
-A7F9;MODIFIER LETTER SMALL LIGATURE OE;Lm;0;L;<super> 0153;;;;N;;;;;
-A7FA;LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL TURNED M;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
```

Which includes all of the characters you mention in your question, and obviously many more.

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do to make python's `lower/upper` use a newer version of the UCD - although you can get an updated version of the `unicodedata` module by installing [unicodedata2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodedata2/8.0.0). But that doesn't really help you much.

It looks like your only real choices are to roll your own `lower/upper` functions, or switch to the latest version of Python 3.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose if that's the list (at least for that block, but other blocks didn't seem to have a problem at least according to random probing) I could add exceptions for those particular characters.  Unfortunately I don't think installing Python 3 is practical at the moment.